# Creating a new object upon key press and adding it to a list

Tags: c++, list, sfml

I'm building a space shooter game with c++ and sfml.
Right now I have a bullet class which is just a circleshape with some movement logic to it. I need a way to store the bullet objects, draw them, and also undraw/delete them once they hit something or goes out of range. I'm adding them to a list and each bullet object has a bool attribute called alive which I constantly update based on distance traveled or collision with other objects. I set alive to false whenever it collides or goes out of range. I then iterate through the list to remove all objects whose alive attribute is false. This sounds like a horrible method though, and would the bullet objects even be freed after i delete them from the list?

Here is my code so far:

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::T)) {
        Bullet newBullet(mySub.getSprite().getPosition().x + 64, mySub.getSprite().getPosition().y + 20);
        bulletList.push_back(newBullet);
}
list<Bullet>::iterator it = bulletList.begin();
while (it != bulletList.end()) {
       if (it->getNoDraw() == true) {
            bulletList.erase(it++);
       }
       else {
            it->update();
            if (it->getBulletSprite().getPosition().x > mySub.getSprite().getPosition().x + 1200) {
                    it->setNoDraw();
                }
            }
        }

cout << "list size " << bulletList.size() << endl;
for (list<Bullet>::iterator it = bulletList.begin(); it != bulletList.end(); ++it) {
            window.draw(it->getBulletSprite());
}
```

I'm creating a new bullet object and adding it to the bulletList each time I press T, but it's not actually adding the new bullet to the list since bulletList.size() always prints 0. Any thoughts how I can do this effectively?

Comment: Why do you use a for-loop to draw. Can't you draw that bullet in the else part of the if(it->getNoDraw() == true) ? It's more effective because you only iterates once through the list.

Comment: You are right. I will update my code later so that I use one iteration to update my objects and draw. It's just that I'm used to updating all my objects, then drawing all of them. If this is the case then I should clear my window before the for-loop huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some faults in the code.
You should reread `erase()` for `list`, it returns the next iterator.
Also your missing advancing in the list when you do not destroy a bullet.

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::T)) {
        Bullet newBullet(mySub.getSprite().getPosition().x + 64,
                         mySub.getSprite().getPosition().y + 20);
        bulletList.push_back(newBullet);
}
list<Bullet>::iterator it = bulletList.begin();
while (it != bulletList.end()) {
    if (it->getNoDraw() == true) {
        it = bulletList.erase(it); // erase already advance it to the next
    } else {
        it->update();
        if (it->getBulletSprite().getPosition().x >
                mySub.getSprite().getPosition().x + 1200) {
            it->setNoDraw();
        }
        it++; // move on to the next position
    }
}

cout << "list size " << bulletList.size() << endl;
for (list<Bullet>::iterator it = bulletList.begin(); 
     it != bulletList.end(); ++it) {
    window.draw(it->getBulletSprite());
}
```

Comment: `bulletList.erase(it);` invalidates `it`. Don't forget to update `it` with the returned iterator.

Comment: I changed bulletList.erase(it) to it = bulletList.erase(it) and it seems to work!